# how http method works in servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, get, deployment-descriptor

I have a problem with my `servlet`. I have an HTML page where I call get method for a sum of two numbers when I submit my form it gave me an error. But I already declare get method in my `servlet` class.

**Type:** Status Report

**Message:** HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

**Description** The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.

**Servlet code:**

```java
public class AddServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int a=Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("num1"));
        int b=Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("num2"));
        int sum=a+b;
        resp.getWriter().println(sum+ " doGet method");
    }
}
```

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Servlet</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="add" method="get" >
      Enter 1st number<input type="text" name="num1">
      Enter 2st number<input type="text" name="num2">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

deployment descriptor code:
web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>ServletPractice1</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>AddServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.meet.servlet.AddServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/add</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a valid doGet() method, when you type the servlet’s path in address bar directly, the web container like Tomcat will try to invoke the doGet() method.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException{
    ....        
}
```

Or else Override service method like this:

protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse   response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
}

Answer (score 1):

Servlets is a technology that allows calling code on server.
HttpServlet is an abstraction that allows calling code on server if you decide to use HTTP as a communication protocol that all browsers do anyway.

So in order to understand what happens you should keep in mind that all the communication is done with HTTP (I understand that this question has been asked for educational purposes hence the answer is educational)

Now, HTTP introduces different types of Requests, namely GET, PUT, POST and others.

HttpServlets address this fact by introducing different methods to override (`doGet`, `doPost`, and so on).
It’s simple, if client, the browser that renders the form in this case, wants to use a POST method (and form submit internally does) the `doPost` is called in the servlet.

How do you know which method is used? Well, the easiest is to hit F12 in the browser, go the network tab and inspect the requests, it will tell you what kind of request it is. When you’ll learn **why** actually different types of requests exist you’ll know better. In this case since you want to “submit” an information to the server that potentially will lead to changes on server the POST method is used.

Now its clear that you’ve overridden the wrong method, now your servlet can respond to get requests, but has nothing to do with post requests, hence the error. Override `doPost` and you’re good to go